# Atlassian React Components - TextField Not Accepted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, atlaskit

I am trying to implement [Atlassian React Components](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/components/field-text) in my application.

But [TextField](https://atlaskit.atlassian.com/components/field-text) is not behaving like normal input text field.

It is not forwarding value while submitting form, and giving warning in console

> Warning: styled.input is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { login, resetPassword } from '../helpers/auth';
import TextField from '@atlaskit/field-text';

function setErrorMsg(error) {
  return {
    loginMessage: error
  }
}

export default class Login extends Component {
  state = { loginMessage: null }
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   login(this.email.value, this.pw.value)
     .catch((error) => {
         //catch errors
      })
 }

  render () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            //THIS TEXTFIELD IS MAKING ISSUE

            <TextField autoFocus ref={(email) => this.email = email} placeholder="Email" label="" />
         </div>
         <div className="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" ref={(pw) => this.pw = pw} />
        </div>

         <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
     </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just faced this problem. To solve it you just need to add prop `value=""` to your `<TextField>`